# "Photo rating" database design

Tags: database, database-design

I'm creating a database for keep the photos from Users, and will return the most-daily likes photo < also for each month, year>
Example: i created a photo A, the first day, i got 100 likes, the second day, i got 200 likes, i have total 300likes, so i have to store likes value for each day.
Im thinking a structure likes this :

```
Table Photo[photo_id, user_id, photo_url]

Table Day_Rating[id, photo_id, like_count, date]
//Photo A can have many records in this table

Table Month_Rating[id, photo_id, like_count, month] //month is: 1,2,3,4..12
//Photo A can have many records in this table
```

So when user likes a photo, We will increase by 1 on like_count field for Day_Rating and Month_Rating table.
So for get the daily rating, we will get the most likes with like_count on Day_Rating table, the same with monthly rating.
What do you think about this approach? Can you point me a best practice if  have any better?
 Thanks

Comment: Why not just use the Day_Rating table and determine the monthly rating through a select with restriction on the date? Your Month_Rating Table is absolutely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all you need with just two tables:

```
photo
* id
* posted_by_user_id
* url

rating
* id
* photo_id
* rated_by_user_id
* rated_at
* rate
```

And then just let the database engine do the aggregates. Plus, storing each rating separately will allow you enforce rules like "only one rating by each user" and will allow users to revoke their votes.

Comment: Agreed, but I wouldn't rule out the use of aggregate tables entirely. I'd consider adding them back in on top of this later on if required, since historically the data is unalterable (except if a photo is deleted I suppose).

Comment: Perhaps an indexed/materialized view will suffice. Unless you're operating at near-Facebook scale, most modern RDBMSes will handle aggregations just fine.

Comment: Yes, it's more a matter of being able to efficiently answer "show me the photos with more than n likes per day in this month", which can be indexed with the right aggregate, or "show me the photos in the top 10 by number of likes per week".